# How to make comparison of objects `a == b` to be true?

Tags: javascript, object, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

Here is one of the questions in JavaScript online-test before job interview:

```
function F(){};

var a = new F();
var b = new F();
```

**Q**: How to make comparison `a == b` to be `true`? (e.g. `console.log(a == b) // true`)

I answered that it's impossible because `a` and `b` are two different instances of `F` and equal comparison in JS in case of non-primitives compares reference.

But some time ago I've read article "Fake operator overloading in JavaScript" by Axel Rauschmayer: http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html — and I wonder if there is a hack to fake operator overload in comparison of objects?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b)`

Comment: @roasted, actually not. In topic you mentioned answer is about how to make comparison of objects in the right way. Here is another case.

Comment: @jsguff sorry, just read title i came to a hasty conclusion

Comment: slight edit `function F(){}; => function F(){}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what they mean by "How to make comparison a == b to be true?"

If you're allowed to change the constructor, then you could make your constructor a singleton:

```
function F(){
    if (!F.instance) {
        F.instance = this;
    } else {
        return F.instance;
    }
};
var a = new F();
var b = new F();
if (a === b) {
    //they are the same
}
```

If they want you to keep everything as it is but have a comparision that contains `a == b` then you could write the following:

```
if ("" + a == b) {
}
```

If they want to know methods of determine whether the two objects are instances of the same constructor function, then you could compare the `constructor` property or the `__proto__` property:

```
if (a.constructor === b.constructor) {
}

if (a.__proto__ === b.__proto__) {
}
```

If they want to know methods of dermine whether these two objects have the same properties, you can either compare their JSON string:

```
if (JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)) {
}
```

or you write a function that recursively compares all the properties in both objects (deep comparision).

And the most simple answer to the question "How to make comparison a == b to be true?":

```
var a = new F();
var b = new F();

b = a;

if (a === b) {
    //surprise!!!
}
```

Comment: `a === b` gives false ! the others are working fine

Comment: @CME64 works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hL3fA/

Comment: strange, what is going on?, check this : http://jsbin.com/okinob/3/edit

Comment: @CME64 hmm...where do have that code from? It's not from me ;) http://jsbin.com/usuvod/1/edit

Comment: @basilikum, okay, variant w/ singleton is working fine (`a == b // true`). Thanks!

Comment: @basilikum hahaha, because you are returning the instance and I wanted to be close to the question's case,, thanks for letting me know about the .constructor object, never new it existed in js! :)

Answer (score 0):

my best answer would be this since you can compare different functions:

```
console.log(a.constructor+"" === b.constructor+"");
```

as it returns the functions as strings and then compare them literally .

example test:

```
function f1(){}
function f2(){}
var a = new f1(),
    b= new f2();
console.log(a.constructor+"" === b.constructor+"");
b = new f1();
console.log(a.constructor+"" === b.constructor+"");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/okinob/6/edit)**

note: the `===` sign is not needed as the third would be for type comparison and both are strings at that point so using `==` would do exactly the same thing

**EDIT:** my actual answer to the question however would be: *by removing **new** from the initialization*

Comment: We need **literally** `console.log(a == b) //=> true`. Not `.__proto__`, nor `.constructor`, nor `JSON.stringify(any)`

Comment: @jsguff in that case, do you think you should add `a = a.constructor+""; b=..` before `console.log(a==b);` to keep the condition literally ?

Comment: huh, why not `a = 42; b = 42` ? :) I think they (authors of test) mean exactly the `singleton` pattern, because it's the only way to make literally equal comparison `a == b` to be `true`.

Comment: @jsguff ok then do you mind telling me the constraints of the question? because I don't see you have a chance doing anything to change a= false to true by just looking at it!

Comment: I posted original question (word for word). There weren't any other details.

Comment: @jsguff then you got my answer in the edit :)

Comment: Your suggestion in edit changes sense of provided construction. Hope authors mean that we have exactly two instances of `F`. Maybe there is another right answer on this question (in case if we can't change constructor): **in no way** :)